# Logout of social media sites from my website or app

Tags: php, html

Due to some cases and request from client I need to logout user from the social media website they used to log into my website. (I know its not a good practice but it's client request and must be done.)

The scenario is, users are be able to login to the website and register for some events, (they can use social media to login) the client is going to provide a PC or ipad at the event for those have not registered for the event. These users perhaps use social accounts to login and forget to logout the account. So, I have create a specific page for the client to use that at the event and let users login so the system can distinguish it should take care of logging out the users' social media accounts.

I have found below method to log out the user from **Google**:

```
<img src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?logout&hl=en" />
```

Is there any link for **Linkedin** and **Facebook** to do the same thing?
If this option is available for other social media websites please add to your answer.

Comment: any reason for the -1 ?

Comment: Because your question is totally meaningless. You said "Your client requested you to log the user! out of Google, Facebook & Linkedin". Who is user? Who are you? Google administrator?

Comment: @Trix I am neither the user nor the administrator, please read the scenario I have added to my question. By the way I have already mentioned it is not a good practice. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sign-out URL from all Google account, which is working fine for me:

**For GOOGLE**

https://accounts.google.com/Logout?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FServiceLogin%3Fsacu%3D1&il=true&zx=icxpgruz0yao

**For FACEBOOK** You must have access token to logout

https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=YOUR_REDIRECT_URL&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Hope it will help you.

Comment: The question is asking for LinkedIn and Facebook solutions, not Google.